# PHP bcrypt hash store the salt

Tags: php, function, bcrypt

I have taken the following function for bcrypt from the internet. It outputs a bycrypted password which is exactly what I am looking for. I also took a function for performing a check by using the salt but this function does not provide me with the salt.

```
function bcrypt_hash($password, $work_factor = 8)
{
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3') < 0) throw new Exception('Bcrypt requires PHP 5.3 or above');

    if (! function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        throw new Exception('Bcrypt requires openssl PHP extension');
    }

    if ($work_factor < 4 || $work_factor > 31) $work_factor = 8;
    $salt = 
        '$2a$' . str_pad($work_factor, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '$' .
        substr(
            strtr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)), '+', '.'), 
            0, 22
        )
    ;
    return crypt($password, $salt);
}
```

I need a return of the password and the salt separately. Or is there a way to pull them out of this function separately.

Comment: Why do you need them separate? You could still store them concatenated together in one string. In that case always the first or last X characters are the salt. No need for multiple DB-fields or function return values.

Comment: @feeela Intriguing tell me more. If that is all that is needed for the password field then how do we check it when the user logs in.

Comment: I've posted such a function on snipplr; I think you will get the idea:  http://snipplr.com/view/66454/passwordhash--generate-salted-passwords/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return multiple values from a function, but you CAN return a single data structure which contains multiple values:

```
return array('crypt' => crypt($password, $salt), 'salt' => $salt);
```